# Why does Indonesia have a Hindu national emblem when the country is 86% Muslim?

Tags: religion, islam, indonesia

[image]

- [National emblem of Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_emblem_of_Indonesia)

The Wikipedia article says that --

> Garuda, the disciples carrier or vehicle (vahana) of the Hindu god Vishnu, appears in many ancient Hindu-Buddhist temples of ancient Indonesia. Temples such as Mendut, Borobudur, Sajiwan, Prambanan, Kidal, Penataran, Belahan, and Sukuh depict the images (bas-relief or statue) of Garuda...

Why does Indonesia have a Hindu national emblem when the country is 86% Muslim? Why was there no protest if a handful of gentlemen selected Garuda?

For comparison, say, in Bangladesh, which has a similar percentage of Muslims, I think it is unthinkable to select a Hindu symbol as a national emblem.

Comment: Why does India have a Buddhist symbol as its national emblem (the Lion Capital of Ashoka, commemorating the birth of Gautama Buddha and created by a Buddhist convert) when only 0.7% of the country is Buddhist? History can be a powerful national symbol beyond religious affiliation.

Comment: For that matter, the national emblem of Bangladesh actually explicitly has a star that represents state *secularism*, despite the country being mostly Muslim.

Comment: @Obie2.0, Bangladesh's constitution starts with [bi-smi llāhi r-raḥmāni r-raḥīmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basmala), and according to the constitution, the state religion is Islam.

Comment: @Obie2.0, Ashoka was a Hindu king, he converted to Buddhism after the war with Kalinga, where he killed millions of Buddhists. Besides, India is not a Muslim majority country.

Comment: And yet, the national emblem continues to be the same one based on the 1972 constitution, with four stars representing socialism, secularism, nationalism, and democracy. Which only proves my point.

Comment: And then he erected the Lion Capital to commemorate the birth of Gautama Buddha. It is hard not to see that as a Buddhist symbol.

Comment: @Obie2.0, *And yet, the national emblem continues to be the same one based on the 1972 constitution, with four stars representing socialism, secularism, nationalism, and democracy.* --- and yet, they don't represent any religion.

Comment: Yes, but Bangladesh still kept a symbol of secularism in its emblem despite changing its constitution to be explicitly Islamic. Why is it surprising that Indonesia might keep a symbol of Hinduism despite being majority Muslim? I could cite a dozen-odd other countries in the world that have symbols associated with religions or beliefs not practiced by the majority in their emblems.

Comment: The indonesians do tend to be pretty relaxed about their Islam, compared to their arabic and persian friends. Yeah you do get some fundamentalist types (like you do in any religion or community), but the Indonesians are relaxed kinda people for the most part. They aint gonna let this kinda thing ruin their mojo.

Comment: See also [Britannia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britannia) a symbol of Britain, a Roman goddess/personification re-popularised since the 16th century. Britons don't need to believe in the Roman State Religion to use symbols like Britannia.... So the answer the question is *"Garuda, the disciples carrier or vehicle (vahana) of the Hindu god Vishnu, appears in many ancient Hindu-Buddhist temples of ancient Indonesia."*  But perhaps you could get a better answer on [islam.se] about whether this halal or not.

Comment: Or, the flag of Hawaii has a Union Jack canton despite not being part of the UK or British Commonwealth.

Comment: Insignia of some present and past far-right European political parties include Odinist/Asatru imagery despite the majority of followers not being practicing religious Odinists. The imagery is based more on seeing themselves as modern-day brave warrior Vikings than on actually worshiping Odin and Thor, etc.

Answer (score 7):

The answer (to the extent that there is a particular answer) is provided in the linked Wikipedia article. Sultan Hamid's original design featured an anthropomorphic Garuda, as can be found in the artwork of Indonesia's Hindu temples. The Islamic party, Masyumi, was opposed to this for the reason that you describe: it was too closely related to Hindu mythology. Hamid therefore altered the design to its current form i.e. a stylized eagle. Apparently the Muslims participating in the selection process were satisfied, and thus Indonesia acquired its national emblem.

Comment: So the right answer is that Wikipedia is wrong as the symbol is not really that of *Garuda*. :)

Answer (score 4):

In the past, the Muslims in Indonesia practiced a much more relaxed, tolerant, and loose form of Islam, often mixed with animism and other forms of religion that "strict" adherents of Islam would find unacceptable. Even eating pork and drinking alcohol were not rare. The tudung/hijab were far less common than today.

That changed from the 1970s when the Saudis with their oil money began exporting their more puritanical, "pure/strict", Wahhabist interpretation of Islam to the rest of the world. (See e.g. this 2020 *Guardian* story: [How Saudi Arabia's religious project transformed Indonesia](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2020/apr/16/how-saudi-arabia-religious-project-transformed-indonesia-islam).)

If today Indonesia tried to adopt Garuda as its national emblem for the first time, there would probably be a bit more of a fuss from the much stronger Islamist movements. But in 1950 this was not an issue.

(The same can be said for India's flag with Buddhist wheel adopted in 1947 when secularist elites ran the country vs today when the Hindutva movements are much stronger and the BJP runs the country.)

Comment: Thanks for the Guardian link, a great article. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question mixes up majority of population and freedom of religion in Indonesia.

Even if Indonesia has 86% Muslim, and Indonesia is the state with the highest muslimic poulation, it is NOT a muslimic state.

There is no established state religion, and therefore
the Garuda eagle and other symbols of Indonesia that are used
does not have to fulfil any muslimic/islamic rules like sharia etc.

Official there are six religions in Indonesia with same rights:

- Islam,
- Christianity
  (Catholicism "Katolik", and Protestantism, "Kristen"
  are recognised separately),
- Hinduism,
- Buddhism,
- Confucianism

Even if Garuda may be a hinduistic symbol and the founders of the nation have agreed that this should be the heraldic animal, what does this has to do with 86% muslims if the country takes it freedom of religion serious? ;-)

Like Charle Evans answer is stating: "Apparently the Muslims participating in the selection process were satisfied, and thus Indonesia acquired its national emblem."

-> That's lived healthy cooperation between different religious groups.

> > For comparison, say, in Bangladesh, which has a similar
> > percentage of Muslims, I think it is unthinkable to
> > select a Hindu symbol as a national emblem.

It seems like Bangladesh is for you a "role model" of
holding up the islam.
In fact Bangladesh is one of the counties with the most violence against people of religious minorities like christians. (see link)

"Christian converts of Muslim, Hindu, Buddhist, or ethnic origin suffer the most severe restrictions in Bangladesh,"

https://www.opendoors.de/christenverfolgung/weltverfolgungsindex/laenderprofile/bangladesch
[image: https://www.opendoors.de/christenverfolgung/weltverfolgungsindex/weltverfolgungsindex-karte#rangfolge]

Comment: Christianity is often seen as a short hand for western influence - I wouldn't expect the treatment of Hindu and Christian minorities to be comparable where anti-western sentiments are common.

Comment: Out of scope, but it is the first time I read "muslimic" and first google page basically gives nothing. Don't you mean "islamic" ?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Muslimic @Itération
Maybe not very common, but correct wording..

Comment: What's the difference with islamic ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslims

Comment: @Itération122442 it's a synonym.  Why would you think there is a difference?

Comment: @phoog Because in my native language, real synonyms (with the meaning being actually the very same) does not exist.